# What is the advantage of golang for defining the array int[x][y][z] for [z][y][x]int?

Tags: java, c#, c++, syntax, go

I just start to learn some basic of `golang`, it is little strange for me when looking at the array define syntax.

C++/C#/Java all defines multi-dimensional arrays like:

```
int arr[X][Y][Z]; // C/C++
int[,,] arr = new int[X, Y, Z]; // C#
int[][][] multi = new int[X][Y][Z]; // Java
```

And in go:

```
var arr [Z][Y][X]int32 // go
```

what is the advantage about the syntax?

Comment: Syntax is syntax. Asking about advantages is like asking which syntax is best of the German or English languages.

Comment: It is like Pascal.  The variable name is not in the middle of the type definition.

Comment: **Unrelated:** multi dimension arrays suck (unless you're working with math / scientific stuff and you actually `want` to represent n-dimensional data) Almost every time I've seen a multi-dimensional array in code it was used as a data store for what should have been a proper object model. Make sure you use the proper data structure for your data, please don't use a multi-dimensional array to put people's last name and age.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would not completely agree. Contrary to natural languages, programming languages are designed. So for them a question for rationale behind this or that makes much more sense.

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays don't suck; they can be used in sucky manner (just like anything else). They are a lot more convenient than arrays of arrays. Consider a (mathematical) matrix, for instance.

Comment: **Unrelated #2:** Notice how even without using type inference (in the case of C# it should be `var`), java's syntax is longer. LOL.. most bloated verbose inexpressive language in the history of mankind

Comment: @Dennis_E that's precisely what I said...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg IMHO, syntax matters when I decided to learn a language, and better syntax/highlight some times make the code easy to understand.

Comment: @AlexD An "Intelligent Design" believer among us? Languages aren't designed, they just evolve... ;)

Comment: go syntax is funny :)

Comment: @HighCore You've obviously never programmed in COBOL.

Comment: @FUZxxl given the state of modern languages (such as C#), java == COBOL.. LOL...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Syntaxes of C# and Java were both inspired by C and inherit all the quirks of the C syntax. There is a nice article on why [Go has a different syntax](http://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax):

> #### Go syntax
>
> Languages outside the C family usually use a distinct type syntax in
>   declarations. Although it's a separate point, the name usually comes
>   first, often followed by a colon. Thus our examples above become
>   something like (in a fictional but illustrative language)
>
> ```
> x: int
> p: pointer to int
> a: array[3] of int
> ```
>
> These declarations are clear, if verbose - you just read them left to
>   right. Go takes its cue from here, but in the interests of brevity it
>   drops the colon and removes some of the keywords:
>
> ```
> x int
> p *int
> a [3]int
> ```
>
> There is no direct correspondence between the look of `[3]int` and how
>   to use a in an expression. (We'll come back to pointers in the next
>   section.) You gain clarity at the cost of a separate syntax.

Comment: Have read Pike's article, `Go's declarations read left to right. It's been pointed out that C's read in a spiral! See The "Clockwise/Spiral Rule" by David Anderson.`  Little hard for me to read the array define from left to right though.

Comment: @Gohan It takes a while but it quickly becomes very obvious. [5]int is just an array of *5* ints. Write it down in the same order as you say it.

Answer (score 2):

Another aspect of this kind of [variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) (`var`) is that it is initialized to a **[zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)**

> This initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.

The [declaration is "backward" (coming from C)](http://golang.org/doc/faq#declarations_backwards):

> In C, the notion is that a variable is declared like an expression denoting its type, which is a nice idea, but the type and expression grammars don't mix very well and the results can be confusing; consider function pointers.
>
> Go mostly separates expression and type syntax and that simplifies things (using prefix * for pointers is an exception that proves the rule)